# How to run Maxima from Windows command line

Tags: windows, command, line, maxima

Have Maxima installed on Win10. No problem running wxMaxima and xMaxima via quick launch buttons.

But I'd like to occasionally open basic Maxima from Windows command line. So I'm looking for the maxima.exe file in order to add the path to the environment variables, such that just giving the command "`maxima`" at the command line opens 'er up.

But I'll be darned if I can find maxima.exe anywhere! `wxMaxima.exe` and `xmaxima.exe` are both there.

My Maxima files are at

```
C:\Program Files\Maxima-sbcl-5.38.0
```

...and I've looked everywhere underneath those directories for the maxima.exe executable, to no avail.

Yup, Maxima newbie here (he said unnecessarily!). Suggestions?

Comment: Spot on, @anquegi, many thanks indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Start windows powershell:
Go when you have maxima installed, go inside bin folder and execute the maxima.bat file

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Maxima-sbcl-5.38.1\bin> .\maxima.bat
Maxima 5.38.1 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp SBCL 1.3.4
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) 2+2;
(%o1)                                  4
(%i2)
```

Then you can also add this folder tho the Path variable in Edit the system environment variables. and restart your powershell. Then you can execute maxima without going to that directory.

Comment: How do you exit maxima from the command line?